Clarification Needed on Potential Function Term in Discrete Klein-Gordon Equation Transformation
I am studying the PhD thesis Dynamics of nonlinear lattices: asymptotic behavior and study of the existence and stability of tracked oscillations and I have observed a mistake at a function on page 69. In my question, the observed mistake was notated as (*)
The study of the dynamics of the discrete Klein - Gordon equation (DKG) with friction is given by the equation :
\begin{equation}
    \ddot {U} _n - k (U_ {n + 1} - 2 U_n + U_ {n - 1}) + \delta\dot {U}_n + W' (U_n) = 0;\quad\beta > 0, \delta > 0 \ (1) \end{equation}
In the above equation, W describes the potential function:$W (U_n) = -\frac {w_d^2} {2} U_n^2 + \frac {\beta w_d^2} {4} U_n^4$ to which every coupled unit $U_n$ adheres. In Eq., $(1)$, the variable $U_n(t)$ is the unknown displacement of the oscillator occupying the n-th position of the lattice, and $k=h^{-2}$ is the discretization parameter. We denote by h the distance between the oscillators of the lattice. The chain (DKG) contains linear damping with a damping coefficient $\delta>0$, while $\beta$ is the coefficient of the nonlinear cubic term.
For the DKG chain (1), we will consider the problem of initial-boundary values, with initial conditions
\begin{equation}
U_n(0) = U_ {n,0} \quad \text{and} \quad \dot{U}_n(0) = U_ {n,1} \in \
\mathbb{R}^{K+2},\ (2)\end{equation}
and Dirichlet boundary conditions at the boundary points $x_0 = -L/2$ and $x_{K+1} = L/2$, that is,
\begin{equation}
U_0 = U_{K+1} = 0, \quad t \geq 0.\ (3)\end{equation}
Therefore, when necessary, we will use the short notation $\Delta_d$ for the one-dimensional discrete Laplacian
\begin{equation}
\{\Delta_d U\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} = U_{n+1} - 2U_n + U_{n-1} \end{equation}
Now we want to investigate numerically the dynamics of the system $(1)-(2)-(3)$. Our first aim is to conduct a numerical study of the property of Dynamic Stability of the system, which directly depends on the existence and linear stability of the branches of equilibrium points.
For the discussion of numerical results, it is also important to emphasize the role of the parameter $\omega_d^2$. By changing the time variable $t \rightarrow \frac{t}{h}$ , we rewrite Eq. (1) in the form
\begin{equation}\ddot{U}_n - \Delta_d U + \hat{\delta} \dot{U}_n = \Omega_d^2 (U_n - \beta U_n^2), \quad t > 0, \quad \Omega_d^2 = h^2 \omega_d^2, \quad \hat{\delta} = h \delta \ (*) \end{equation}
We consider spatially extended initial conditions of the form:$$ U_n(0) = U_{n,0} = a \sin \left( \frac{j \pi h n}{L} \right), \quad j = 1, \ldots, K $$
where  $ h = \frac{L}{K+1} $ is the distance of the grid and $ a > 0$ is the amplitude of the initial condition
We also assume zero initial velocity:
$\dot{U}_n(0) = U_{n,1} = 0 $.
My Proof
Initial Equation:
The initial discrete Klein-Gordon equation with friction is given by:
$$ \ddot{U}_n - k (U_{n+1} - 2U_n + U_{n-1}) + \delta \dot{U}_n + W'(U_n) = 0, \quad \beta > 0, \delta > 0 \ \ (1) $$
The potential function $W(U_n)$ is:
$$W(U_n) = -\frac{w_d^2}{2} U_n^2 + \frac{\beta w_d^2}{4} U_n^4 $$
Step-by-step Transformation:

List item Discrete Laplacian:
The discrete Laplacian operator $\Delta_d U$ is given by:
$$ \Delta_d U = U_{n+1} - 2U_n + U_{n-1}. $$
Therefore, the equation (1) can be rewritten as:
$$ \ddot{U}_n - k \Delta_d U + \delta \dot{U}_n + W'(U_n) = 0. $$

Potential Derivative $W'(U_n)$:
The derivative of the potential function $ W(U_n)  is:
$$ W'(U_n) = -w_d^2 U_n + \beta w_d^2 U_n^3. $$
Substituting $ W'(U_n)$  into the equation, we get:
$$ \ddot{U}_n - k \Delta_d U + \delta \dot{U}_n - w_d^2 U_n + \beta w_d^2 U_n^3 = 0. $$

Discretization Parameter:
Given $ k = h^{-2} $, we have:
$$ \ddot{U}_n - h^{-2} \Delta_d U + \delta \dot{U}_n - w_d^2 U_n + \beta w_d^2 U_n^3 = 0. $$

List item Change of Time Variable:
Change the time variable $t \rightarrow \frac{t}{h}$. Under this change:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \rightarrow \frac{d}{d(t/h)} = h \frac{d}{dt}. $$
Consequently:
$$ \ddot{U}_n \rightarrow h^{-2} \ddot{U}_n, \quad \dot{U}_n \rightarrow h^{-1} \dot{U}_n. $$

Substitute Time Derivatives:
Substituting these into the equation gives:
$$ h^{-2} \ddot{U}_n - h^{-2} \Delta_d U + h^{-1} \delta \dot{U}_n - w_d^2 U_n + \beta w_d^2 U_n^3 = 0. $$

Normalize and Simplify:


Multiply through by $ h^2 $ to simplify:
$$ \ddot{U}_n - \Delta_d U + h \delta \dot{U}_n - h^2 w_d^2 U_n + \beta h^2 w_d^2 U_n^3 = 0. $$

Define New Parameters:
Define the new parameters:
$$ \Omega_d^2 = h^2 w_d^2, \quad \hat{\delta} = h \delta. $$
Substituting these, we get the transformed equation:
$$ \ddot{U}_n - \Delta_d U + \hat{\delta} \dot{U}_n = \Omega_d^2 (U_n - \beta U_n^3). $$

Final Transformed Equation:


Thus, the correctly transformed equation becomes:
$$ \ddot{U}_n - \Delta_d U + \hat{\delta} \dot{U}_n = \Omega_d^2 (U_n - \beta U_n^3), \quad t > 0, \quad \Omega_d^2 = h^2 w_d^2, \quad \hat{\delta} = h \delta. $$

What clarification do you need?

@Gonçalo That $\Omega_d^2 (U_n - \beta U_n^3)$ is correct not $\Omega_d^2 (U_n - \beta U_n^2)$

It's probably a typo. Compare with the first equation on page 4 of the thesis, or with Eq. (1.1) of the paper Dynamical transitions between equilibria in a dissipative Klein-Gordon lattice, mentioned on page 6.

@Gonçalo So my proof is correct. Thank you so much
